# Implement JSX in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jsxgraph

I would like to implement JSX Graph on my wordpress website and installed the plugin in the way you recommended. But if you have a look at the website and scroll down you only see the frame of the JSXGraph applet but not the grid etc. So what can I do to display it right? Here is the code:

```
<p><script type="text/javascript"><br />
 var board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('box', {boundingbox: [-10, 10, 10, -10], axis:true});<br />
</script></p>
```

and in the head

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/distrib/jsxgraph.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/distrib/jsxgraphcore.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops, this is outdated information. Since your wordpress runs with https, also JSXGraph must be included using https. Please, remove `http:` from the links like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/distrib/jsxgraph.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/distrib/jsxgraphcore.js"></script>
```

Best wishes,
Alfred